# jQuery animations, loading text files to variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, jquery-animate

With my code I want to animate class `".donator"` and `".follower"` each time a change in text file (..recent_donator.txt or ..recent_follower.txt) appears. My code is partially working but only with jQuery animation `fadeIn` or `fadeOut` , anytime I want to do anything else or set custom animation with `.animate()` nothing happens. How can I add other animations than just "fade"?

HTML:

```
<div class="donator animated slideInUp"><div class="unskew" id="donatorid"></div>
</div>
<div class="follower animated slideInUp"><div class="unskew" id="followerid"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 .follower {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 180px;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: #FFF;
}

.donator {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 580px;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: #FFF;
}
```

JS:

```
var oldFollow, oldDonate;
var auto_refresh = setInterval(function() {

  oldFollow = $('#followerid').html();

  $('#followerid').load("../Muxy/most_recent_follower.txt");

  oldDonate = $('#donatorid').html();

  $('#donatorid').load("../Muxy/most_recent_donator.txt");

  //  console.log(oldFollow);
  //  console.log($('#followerid').html());
}, 1000);


var auto_check = setInterval(function() {

  if ($('#followerid').html() != oldFollow) {
    // actions (animations, div changes etc.)
        $('.follower').fadeOut(500, function() {
            $('.follower').fadeIn(500);
        });
  }
    if ($('#donatorid').html() != oldDonate) {
    // actions (animations, div changes etc.)
        $('.donator').fadeOut(500, function() {
            $('.donator').fadeIn(500);
        });
  }
}, 200);
```

Comment: Can you give an example of some code that isn't working for you?

Comment: Any other animation like `$('.follower').slideDown(500, function() {
            $('.follower').slideUp(500);
        }` or `$('.follower').animate({top: -=100px}, function() {
            $('.follower').animate({top= +=100px});`

Comment: Do you want the animations to occur simultaneously, or one after the other?

Comment: Simultaneously at the start, but then only depending on the file change, I think the code is correct till the animation moment but i could be wrong.

Comment: Have you checked the console to make sure you aren't getting any errors? Also there are certain css properties that won't animate that way, such as color

Comment: Sorry for confusion, everything is working, just simple syntax errors on mine. The other problem I have is setting delay on displaying new content of the text file. What I mean is I want to display the old value loaded from the text file for the next 1-2 seconds, then animation, then display new value, then animation. I don't know if it is understandable.